# Delete animation of object

Tags: animation

Sorry for a simple question, but I have animated the movement of a door; just a movement of the X axis. Turns out I'll do this in code instead, so I want to delete this animation. How do I delete an animation completely from an object?

For that matter, at this point I could just as well delete everything animation related, so any hint of how to do that would be OK.

Comment: This is one of the most confusing aspects of blender. I have been using blender for 17 years not an I still the whole, "Materials,Textures.Actions, Poses." creation and deletion process confusing. I know it has something to do with " the object oriented nature of blender" but that is for programmers, not hobbyist/artist like me.

Answer (score 28):

The fastest way I know to delete all the animations of an object:

- Select object
- Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Type "Remove anim"
- The menu item "Remove Animation" will appear.
- Using keyboard, select that menu item and press Enter or
  Return.

V2.8+ : Alternatively after selecting the objects, go to *Object > Animation > Clear Keyframes*, and click again on the prompt asking you to *Remove Animation*.

I do this often. I wish I knew an even faster way. This way, you only need one mouse click, to select the object.

Comment: I'm in Blender 2.9 and pressing space bar plays the animation

Answer (score 7):

## Deleting animation of specific property:

You can also right click on the animated value and click *clear keyframes* to automatically delete all keyframes on that value.

[image]

In the case of a transform channel, *clear keyframes* will clear the keyframes of the X Y and Z. If you only want to delete all the keyframes on one channel, right click on that channel and select *Clear single keyframe*.

## Deleting all animation:

Go to the dopesheet or graph editor, make sure that the *show keyframe on selected objects only* option (cursor icon) is disabled and that *show keyframes on hidden objects* (ghost icon) is enabled, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and then press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A scripting approach, the following will clear all animation data from all selected objects.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
for ob in context.selected_objects:
    ob.animation_data_clear()
```

Replace `context.selected_objects` with `context.scene.objects` for all in the current scene, or `bpy.data.objects` to remove all animation data from all objects.

Comment: Good idea to post this here. Should we add how to remove the current keyframe only?

Comment: It's the scripting equivalent of @megtwin 's answer, removing all animation data, as requested in q.. so I say no as to adding specifics like keyframes or nla strips.

Comment: You are right, just thought it would be nice to have :)

Comment: Beautiful... very done !

Answer (score 6):

You can also go to the outliner, click on armature, right click on animation and select "Clear animation data". :)

Answer (score 5):

Select any keyframe in the timeline, or similar, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. To check that a keyframe is selected, the frame number in the bottom left is orange (in the default theme); You can also press the highlighted button to jump to the next keyframe, or <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, I have several animations attached to a model.  One for walking, one for running.  Each part of the model has its own set: [leftfoot]Walk, [leftfoot]Run, etc...

The quickest way to remove them all was to go to the NLA Editor and they are all listed there to be easily deleted.
This first requires you to use the solution of @user14463 to clear the current model's animations for all parts.

Next, open the NLA Editor and all the animations are listed there.  Select each one, and press X to delete it.

[image]

However, I found that this does not always work.... for some reason I just cannot get rid of these actions, and they seem to multiply when I do things like copy objects around, and they end up with phantom objects referring to them.

So, an easy way to get rid of an action is to open the python console.

For example, I had the following actions:

- [StomperChassis]Walk
- [StomperChassis]Walk.001
- [StomperChassis]Walk.002
- [StomperChassis]Walk.003

I don't know where the .001, .002, and .003 versions came from, but I don't want them!

In the console:

```
# Get the collection of actions
actions = bpy.data.actions

# Print all the action names
for actionname in actions.keys():
    print(actionname)

# (printout omitted)
# And now, remove action "[StomperChassis]Walk.001"
actions.remove(actions['[StomperChassis]Walk.001'])

# Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the best and easiest way was to simply go to menu Object > Track > Clear and Keep Transformation (Clear Track)

You can also find this option by typing it after pressing F3

Answer (score 0):

Go to nonlinear animation window(not have default keybinding for it).

1. Left click on *Track > Edit Tab  > Delete Tracks*
2. Go in *Dope Sheet* select *Action Editor* and choose any track you do not like, and uncheck it under *Fake User* (shield icon filled with white, if filled - click on it). If track owner is not *Fake User* (shield icon not filled) you can do nothing.
3. Save changes.
4. Restart Blender (or just reopen your blend file)
   and enjoy your animation list clean from unwanted animation tracks.