# How to delete all the keyframes from multiple objects?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, keyframes

I have about 30 objects which are keyframed. Is there a fast way way to delete all the animation data from all of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of:

1. Select all the objects
2. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>← Left arrow</kbd> twice to get the the *Animation* screen.
3. Hover over the dope sheet and select everything (<kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Gandalf3! You really helped me. But somehow, when I selected all the objects in my 3d window, hovered the cursor over the dope sheet and pressed 'X' not all the animation data was deleted. I had to press 'A' in a dope sheet and then 'X' to get rid of all actions.

Comment: oh yes, I should probably add that

Comment: Oh, and I've found the related topic btw: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/delete-animation-of-object

Comment: In Blender 2.91 this seems only to work for visible objects. I select all objects (Outliner > A) then go either to the Timeline or to the Animation screen, press A and X followed by "Delete Keyframes".
All visible keyframes are deleted, but the ones I made invisble by a keyframe are not shown and therefore not deleted.
Is there a trick for 2.91?

Comment: Also make sure that 'Show Hidden' in the Dope Sheet is selected.