# Blender seems to force motion tracking - can't get scaling right for single image

Tags: rendering, transforms

I hope I've described this correctly.  I don't know Blender so well, and have watched countless videos, but am on a deadline for some work.  The client knows this isn't my usual realm, but has asked me to give it my best.

I've gotten everything set, but when I render the image, objects are resized to before I scaled them properly.  Another thread hinted that Blender may be using keyframe data, though I have none, but looking at the Dope Sheet, it does seem it's tracked all the resizing, and I wonder if this plays a role?  It's only rendering the image as it very first appeared in the file, and in that case, one of the objects is way too small relative to the other.

In effect, I just want to have the image rendered corresponding to what I have in my 3D view when I click to render.  Can someone please offer a little guidance?  Thank you!

Edit: Added screenshots... you can see everything is sized appropriately in the first image, but upon render, in the second, you see the model inside the cargo container model is suddenly too big for the container.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help to see some images! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post   You say "objects are resized to before I scaled them properly"? Did you scale them in Object mode, and if so did you apply the Scale using Ctrl-A > Scale?

Comment: Ctrl-A, Scale doesn't seem to let me scale. I've just been using S to scale. I'm in 2.79, as my computer can't handle newer OpenGL requirements.  ....  I'll try to add a couple images.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I went back to take screenshots of everything, and re-rendered the image, it worked as expected this time....  I have no clue why it wasn't using the scaling before, and what changed this time.  Really weird....  I'll keep this thread updated should it happen again, as I have several more images to produce still.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah ok. I only have versions back to 2.80 here, but a quick search seems to infer that the method to **apply** the scale to an object was the same in 2012 as it is in the latest versions. [This](https://youtu.be/XCEN0qQOsIA?t=354) snippet of a tutorial from Andrew Price using Blender 2.62 uses that hotkey combination.

Comment: It's happening again... I started running into problems getting a background image to work with the render, or finding a workaround to get the background image to display... it shows in camera view, but textures won't.  Textures show in render, but background image won't.

Comment: I'm adding screenshots now for the original problem, since that is happening again...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough knowledge of early versions of Blender to tell what's going on. I think folks here will need to see your Blend file to see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, John.  I've added the link to the blend file, now.  Also now that I've finally added the background image, I see some part of it isn't rendering with the rest, and so there is a "blank corner" in the rendered image now.  I'm attaching a new screenshot for that.

Comment: I've just had a quick look at your blend file in version 3.5 and as I suspected  the scale hasn't been applied to any of your objects. The container (which for some reason has keyframes on it that will currently stop it being manually scaled) has a scale of 1.825, the machinery object is scaled to -0.137, and the plane to 8.025! All three would show a scale of 1 if the scale had been applied. As I said, I don't know Blender 2.79 so can't really advise further. (Also there are no materials in the file so we can't see any textures here.)

Comment: Thanks, John, you've been hugely helpful. 

I don't know how the keyframes got there (I have a hunch), but removing all keyframes was the answer, it seems.  I also figured out that an add-on for importing image as plane to use for the background hadn't actually activated (seems there's always an extra button to press to activate things), and going back to re-input that add-on, and saving preferences, allowed that to work.  So this is moving along much better now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was that there were keyframes being used, which there shouldn't have been.  I followed this post: [How to delete all the keyframes from multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18932/how-to-delete-all-the-keyframes-from-multiple-objects)
to remove the keyframes.  I also had to re-import an add-on that hadn't imported the first time for the background images, which was the import image as plane add-on.  Be sure to save preferences after choosing an add-on, or it won't import!

Comment: In later blender versions from 2.8 onwards the settings are saved automatically when you close the preferences dialog if you have Auto-save Preferences checked in the save preferences section. From memory I think that's checked by default. Glad you got there in the end!

Comment: Good to know, and good to share with others.  I've definitely dealt with some 2.79 issues.  Thanks again for all your contributions here, John!