# Can not delete actions in action editor even with Shift + x

Tags: animation

I can't delete any of these actions. I did do Shift + X but they just keeps showing up. There's no O next to them:

[image]

Here's blend file:

Comment: and after you save it and then open the file again, are the actions still there?

Comment: They are :( I don't know what's going on. Shift + X like crazy

Comment: Ok thanks. It's really likely that is another bug in blender. Here's topic on it in BA site:    http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?376893-Blender-dev-should-focus-on-improving-animation-tools-and-docs-(can-t-delete-Actions)/page2&highlight=can+not+delete+action+editor . F*ck it

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/delete-animation-of-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably best way is change Outliner into Blender File mode, right click on action and click delete.
[image: Delete Action]

Answer (score 20):

When you delete an action, it still exists in Orphan Data:

[image]

Although ther's no O next the action name, it will be removed after saving and reopening the file.

**If you want to delete all Orphan Data immediatly, just click the "Purge All" button.**

**NOTE**
If you want any orphan date to have a Fake User and prevent them to be deleted, click on the x:

[image]

Comment: Wow... I never knew something like orphan data existed

Answer (score 19):

If you want to delete a single action do it in the ***NLA Editor***.
[image]

If you want to delete all actions, go to the ***Outliner*** and type *animation* in a search window. Hover your cursor as pictured below, press RMB-->*Clear Animation Data*. All your actions should disapear.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way is to delete actions via the *Outliner* while having it in Blender File mode.

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F9</kbd>
2. Click on the image-stack icon and select *Blender File* from the drop-down menu

[image: 2.]

3. Expand the *Actions* drop-down menu, right-click on the action you want to delete and click on *Delete* (pressing the  <kbd>Del</kbd> button while having an action has no effect as of Blender 2.92)

[image: 3.]

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution I needed by accident. I was fishing around the the outliner after trying all of the steps above and stumbled on this guy

[image]

This was the action that I couldn't get rid of, either in the action editor or the NLA editor. I even tried the Purge All Orphan Data trick, and that did not get rid of this action. The only thing that did was opening up this animation hierarchy and deleting it from there. And finally it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I've managed to figure it out eventually! If shift+X cant remove the actions completely, you could do as Gonzou suggets to delete ALL of them.

To delete each of the actions, Go to NLA editor, delete the Action Stash labeled the name of the action you want to remove. Then you can Shift+X to remove the action completely in Action editor!

Comment: Not working to me

Comment: Have you tried all of the replies above?

Comment: Yes, I did it all but nothing works.