# A model "jumps" back after I move it

Tags: modeling, animation, keyframes, shape-keys

If I move the model in space it remains there. But after I move to another frame it "jumps" back where it was before.

- I already deleted all the animations and used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - clear parent,
  but it doesn't help.
- I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply it's position, but it forces model to jump to the another place, and if I then do it again it jumps to the other place
  again.

Why is it happening?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: are you sure you that you are keyframing the position of your model.

Comment: Sounds like your object still has keyframes on it.  Check the timeline, are there any yellow bars in it when the object is selected?

Comment: Unless you create a new keyframe the object will move to the position set on the previous one.

Comment: You probably have an inserted keyframe as @PGmath suggested. Please see this answer to remove all animations: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/can-not-delete-actions-in-action-editor-even-with-shift-x

Comment: Thank you very much, everybody, perhaps it was a keyframe I missed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the object was not animated/keyframed and it was not parented to anything else.
The solution was to delete the `Rigid Body` under `Physics Properties`