Why does some of my models keep randomly going to the blender origin?
Many times when working in blender I see that some of the models I make go back to the blender origin. I am not sure why this happens, but I assume its some setting i keep pressing by mistake. It's getting pretty annoying now and want this to stop. I am not setting the objects origin to "geometry to origin" so not sure what else it could be.
Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Are you doing Ctrl + A > Location when you're applying rotation or scale ever? Because that's what that does specifically. If you do Apply All in the Apply Transforms menu it will do that as well in addition to Scale and Rot.

Also are you saying your models keep going to the World origin or is your model staying in the same place and you notice that only it's origin is at the World origin?

the models keep going to the world origin. And I always apply all transforms to all my objects.

If you apply All transforms the object's Origin will be reset to the World origin so don't do that! Normally you would just apply the Scale and Rotation. However applying the Location shouldn't change the object's position. I think we'll need to see a simple Blend file where that has happened. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78371/a-model-jumps-back-after-i-move-it
