# How do I move an object using the script editor?

Tags: python

I have looked for a while and cannot find an answer to this simple question: What code do I write to make a cube go from anywhere to anywhere? I have a spaceship that I want a player to be able to move and rotate using keys. How would I do this? Is there a simple way to make the ship move to anywhere I have not found yet?

Comment: That's not possible anymore since the game engine has been removed. You would have to use a game engine like godot, unity or unreal with dedicated player controls for that.

Comment: that explains a few things

Comment: How to set the location (without player control): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39451/cant-set-the-location-of-the-object-by-program