# Bones change rotation to first frame of last animation

Tags: rigging, export

I want the bones rotation of my model to be at 0,0,0 when exporting. But it automatically sets the rotation of the bones to the the first frame of the last animation used. I cant seem find anything on the internet about this and I've been looking for ages. How do i fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the action isn't still associated with the object, either via the action editor or NLA.  To see if an object has an animation look at the outliner

[image: Animation in outliner]

Here the Cube has an action (CubeAction.001) a driver and has NLA tracks.  The camera has no animation.

[How to clear all animations.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/delete-animation-of-object)

Select all the bones (pose mode)  and  clear transform
[image]

You can make a "zero" animation action here by inserting a LocRotScale.

Comment: But when i save & reopen the file it goes back to how it was before. The transform doesn't stay.

Comment: Is the action still linked to the object? via either the action editor, or NLA

Comment: I think so. How can i tell, does it have anything to do with this problem?.

Comment: Has anyone got a solution?, i need to fix this as soon as possible so i can continue with my progress.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to tell  if your rig has animation data. Given I provided it as answer, yes It may have something to do with your problem, or at least I'm under the impression it does.  If the property gui elements are (at least in default theme) yellow or green, then you have an action, if they are grey but set it is most likely NLA. Does it export ok after you have cleared the transforms.

Comment: I'm quite new to blender i know most modeling tools (I think) but I've just finished going through some animation tutorials which only explained how to animate objects so sorry if this is nooby question but if i have to remove the action from the object (Which i think is what i have to do from how you explained your answer) wont that delete the animation?.

Comment: It unlinks it from the object (a user) . Objects, actions (all blender datablocks) are only deleted if they have zero users, you can prevent this by setting the fake user https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/datablocks.html#fake-user

Comment: When i cleared animations they wont play anymore when i export to unity engine and after clearing animations, 7 animations start to show up for the model: Idle, Bones|Idle, Bones|Running, Bones|Walk, Character|Idle, Character|Running, Character|Walk,? Can you explain this, is there hidden animations somewhere or something?. Its not really a big problem but its kinda bugging me since there's 7 animations when i only need 3.