# N Panel (Location & Rotation Boxes are YELLOW) ... Makes my Mesh Load up in the Blend file in a new location with different scale

Tags: mesh, panel

I have this mesh inside my blend file. Whenever I load this/open this blend in Blender, the mesh appears in a new location as opposed to how I saved it. The only thing I see is that the boxes in the panels are yellow as opposed to normal color. How can I change this so that this mesh appears with its same scale and location when I open the blend file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XD you animated the mesh. The boxes turn yellow when you animated something. Do you see that yellow line in the Timeline? That means that you animated the mesh to a new location from Frame 1, all the way to the yellow line!
[Delete animation of object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15198/delete-animation-of-object) 
Here is how to get rid of the yellow line, which would get rid of the animation. :D

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! That solved it, I did not recognize that! Good tip!