# What is the proper way to delete all keyframes for entire timeline including MeshVertex?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline, dopesheet

I found [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215843/how-can-i-delete-keyframes-and-animation-data-for-all-selected-objects) but it didn't help. The only source i found that clears "all" animation data is

```
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    o.animation_data_clear()
```

But this does not remove animation data or keyframes for *MeshVertex* data

[image]

I have a lot of keyframes added throughout the timeline using

```
for v in o.data.vertices:
    v.keyframe_insert(data_path="co", frame=1)
```

I think it's wrong and weird if you have to manually loop through all the frames to delete those frames like this, which also causes an error if the other frames have no keyframes.

```
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    o.animation_data_clear()
    for v in o.data.vertices:
        for f in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_end):
            v.keyframe_delete(data_path="co", frame=f)
```

Is there no single function that will just clear **ALL keyframes** at once? Is manual looping the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Since vertices fcurve are not stored in objects, you can access it from `bpy.data.actions`

```
import bpy

actions = bpy.data.actions
for a in actions:
    actions.remove(a)
```

Comment: nice this works! thank you so much!